# Update Cordova Windows Platform within Apache Tools for Cordova?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

The Cordova folks updated the windows platform to 3.8.0 a couple of weeks ago... I'm using Apache Tools for Cordova CTP3 within VS 2013u4 and haven't found an option or tool to update the underlying cordova platform.

How do I ensure that my windows platform is at 3.8.0?

NOTE: Apache Tools for Cordova does NOT use the Cordova CLI, so the folders holding my VS project are not Cordova projects and thus the Cordova CLI will not update them. Or list the platforms even!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shortcoming will be addressed in the future. Tools for Apache Cordova does in fact use the Cordova CLI under the hood.

See "Manually Updating the Cordova Version" here for details on updating in the short term:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757054.aspx

Comment: That page provides instructions for updating Cordova, true, but that's not what I need--apologies if I was unclear. How does one update the windows platform within Cordova? When not using CTP3, one would type `cordova platforms rm windows` and then `cordova platforms add windows` from the root of the cordova project. Since Tools uses the CLI, where would I type these CLI commands to update just the windows platform for my solution? Thanks!

Comment: Updating the version of the CLI will result in updating the Cordova platform version as well on next build.  VS will detect that an old version of the platform is present and update it.  To get Windows 3.8.0, simply use Cordova CLI 4.3.0.  If you want to update Windows to something not "pinned" by the CLI, then there is not a clean way to do that today.  We're working on introducing support for that.  You can, however, go into the bld/Debug or bld/Release folders and run Cordova commands.  However, note that these do get removed as the result of a "clean" event.